# jQuery ui slider - if value increases or decreases when sliding

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Basically i want run two functions when value increases and decreases. How can I check user slides to the right (when value increases) and to the left (when value decreases) here is fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/BxY99/436/

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set a temp var and compare it to the slider's current value.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/BxY99/438/)**

```
var last = 0;
$(".slider").slider({
    range: "min",
    value: 1,
    min: 1,
    max: 600,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        if (ui.value > last) $("#amount").val("this is increasing");
        if (ui.value < last) $("#amount").val("this is decreasing");
        last = ui.value;
    }
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this : http://jsfiddle.net/BxY99/439/

```
var lastValue = 0;
$(".slider").slider({
        range: "min",
        value: 1,
        min: 1,
        max: 600,
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
        if(ui.value > lastValue) {
            $( "#amount" ).val( "this is increasing" );
        } else {
            $( "#amount" ).val( "this is decreasing" );
        }
        lastValue = ui.value;
    }
});​
```