# Append/Remove Text with Jquery UI Slider

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want to append and remove random text to a div with the Jquery UI Slider. It should add text by moving the slider handle in one direction, while removing text in the other direction. I read the API, but I couldn't find information about directional events.

```
var rhetoric = ["lorem", "ipsum", "consectetur", "adipiscing"];
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#slider-vertical').slider({
    orientation: "vertical",
    min: 0,
    max: rhetoric.length - 1,
    step: 1,
    value: 3,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      $("#ipsum-text").append(rhetoric[ui.value] + " ");
    }
  });
  $("#ipsum-text").val($("#slider-vertical").slider("value", 0));
});
```

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/95b2gs4u/2/)

Comment: This this should give you what you need, http://stackoverflow.com/a/6036142/1143670

Answer (score 0):

I got it! I combined a [solution from another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12431894/jquery-ui-slider-if-value-increases-or-decreases-when-sliding). Basically, you need to use the change in value to trigger the text add or remove. The full code is below:

```js
var rhetoric = ["lorem", "ipsum", "consectetur", "adipiscing"];
var last = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#slider-vertical').slider({
    orientation: "vertical",
    range: "min",
    min: 0,
    max: rhetoric.length,
    step: 1,
    value: rhetoric.length + 1,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      if (ui.value < last) $("#ipsum-text").append('<span class="ipsum-item">' + rhetoric[ui.value] + '</span>&nbsp;');
      if (ui.value > last) $(".ipsum-item:last-child").remove();
      last = ui.value;
    }
  });
  $("#ipsum-text").val($("#slider-vertical").slider("value"));
});
```